# How to activate the onchange function with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, jsf-2

I am developing a Java Web Application with JSF 2.2. I am combining another frontend tecnologies, however my specific problem is easily to explain with the next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="test" value="Initial value" onchange="alert('I changed my value')"/>
    <button onclick="updateTest()">Cambiar el valor</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateTest() {
          document.getElementById("test").value = "|" + document.getElementById("test").value;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the user modify the input value, the browser show the alert message, but when the user clicked on the button the browser not detect input value was to changed and I need when the user clicked on the button, the input changes its value and the browser launch the alert message.

Why I need this crazy process? Because I would like to use another JavaScript frameworks that modify the front-end of different way that JSF. I have a modal to change a input value with the javascript framework code pure and I would like when this value to changed, also JSF detects the new input value.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How is this question jsf related?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an input event listener, see the following code snippet for a basic example that should get you there.

**Edit:**  This has been updated to show you can trigger the `oninput` event listener even in the even that you programmatically change the value.

```js
document.querySelector('#test').oninput = function() {
  console.log(this.value);
}

// Modal code
{
  document.querySelector('#test').value = 'new value';
  document.querySelector('#test').oninput();
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
```